# Activity: Launch from history VS Launch from icon

Tags: android, android-activity, launcher

What is the difference between launching the activity from local history (click on resent task button or long click on home button) to lunch the activity by clicking on app icon?

In my app I got two activities in the stack A (launcher), B.
When launching from recent history, B is resumed.
When launching from icon B is destroyed(finish not been called) and A is resumed.

A is defined as launcher singleTask, B launch mode is not set(So it use default).

Why is there a difference at all?
Isn't it's supposed to be the same action?

I looked in two the activity dump and the intents appears to be identical:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity

Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.my.package/.MainActivity bnds=[14,108][354,548] (has extras) }
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.my.package/.MainActivity (has extras) }
```

`bnds=[14,108][354,548]` Is just the bounds of the screen that lunched the intent

I debugged the extras and they are identical both got one integer key

```
profile -> 0
```